Confinement, Holographic QCD, Seiberg-Witten Theory
I have seen a bunch of articles that all try to show confinement using AdS/QCD or Holographic QCD method.
I pretty much know that the lastest attempt to prove confinement based on breaking SUSY even further in the supersymmetric 4d proof of confinement by Seiberg-Witten Theory dates back to this 1997 article: controlled soft breaking of $\mathcal{N}=1$ SQCD
which to me is actually a failure, as it cannot decouple the adjoint Gauginos of the softly SUSY broken SQCD, and their mass is supposed to remain much below the SQCD scale parameter, and all the spurious field VEVs are limited to a certain regime and the theory has nothing to do with the YM that one knows given all these assumptions! As of today, there has been no attempt to implement this limit!(27 years)
There I want to pose the same question, regarding the more recent approach of AdS/QCD.
Can anyone please give an account of a realistic QCD confinement proof strategy within the scope of this approach?
Or at least give an account of what we know more about QCD regarding confinement, using the AdS/QCD method? Is it anyhow different in its way of SUSY breaking limit implementation, from that of Seiberg-Witten Theory?
I don't know Holography, but I do know SUSY and Seiberg-Witten work very well. But I prefer to be given an answer assuming a full knowledge of AdS/CFT and String Theory.

Edit: There's this work done, by Witten in 1998, that tries to speculate (again based on SUSic models) a proof of confinement. The question would be are these lines of thoughts implemented formally by now? At least to deliver YM from the $(0,2) \ 6d$ exotic theory(which I guess refers to the famous unkown SCFT)

Not a theorist but intuitively I would suggest that you are going at this from the wrong angle. Quarks are probably not fundamental fields but components of topological states, so instead of trying to "synthesize" quark pair, triples etc. from (non-existing) single states, try to understand what a topological state is within the structure of QFT.

@FlatterMann could you provide a reference for this? I have never heard about quarks in this way

As far as I know, confinement is not a solved problem. It does not seem likely that it can be explained in the context of SUSY. The confinement scale is at the QCD scale which is at least two orders of magnitude below the electroweak scale. The LHC tried to find SUSY at the electroweak scale and it failed to show up. So we can be fairly certain that there is no SUSY at the confinement scale.

@LolloBoldo I am coming from the solid state angle here. See e.g. fractional quantum hall states. I don't know if one can use similar intuition for Poincare invariant fields as for solid state systems, which are obviously breaking relativity, but I suspect that quarks are not fundamental in the sense that we call e.g. photons or electrons fundamental. I might be wrong.

@FlatterMann thank you for that, i'll search this up :)

@flippiefanus SUSY breaking in Witten-Seiberg proof of confinement doesn't have anything to do with the real world SUSY breaking. It's a technique, and the mechanism of SUSY breaking does not matter as far as it's implemented by adding soft SUSY breaking terms.

@FlatterMann The sort of idea you talk about, is exactly what happens in the Witten-Seiberg theory to the extent that the difference between composite and fundamental fades away. But this can be done only thanks to SUSY based dualities. The problem with real confinement is that it presumably exists in a non-SUSic world.

Maybe it's not exactly the best choice of words but I've already shared the paper by Witten. @Andrew There are a lot more around confinement lines with a superficial search.

Looking through some of the references in the article you linked to, I came across this talk by Klebanov from 2021 which states: "Perhaps the gauge/string duality has provided
us with a “physicist’s proof of confinement” in
some exotic gauge theories like the one
described by the warped deformed conifold.
Yet, we still don’t have a quantitative handle
on the Asymptotically Free theories in 3+1
dimensions."

@BastamTajik Thanks for the details. I am not a theorist, so I can only comment on the phenomenological level. Quarks do obviously not behave like e.g. electrons, so I would suspect that there is "something else" going on there. Whether we want to call this "fundamental/non-fundamental" is a good question. I don't have any preferences at that level. I believe that in a quark-gluon plasma quarks can be modelled as asymptotically free, so maybe this is a human bias for the "empty" vacuum rather than some actual physical difference. The world is just not as simple as we would like it to be.

The conclusion by Klebanov also seems broadly consistent with a list of issues given in this older review from 2009 by Erlich, for example "AdS/QCD has incorrect high energy behavior." FWIW, in a more recent 2023 talk by Witten on confinement, he doesn't say that these issues are solved, so I assume these are still open issues.

Can you please share the Witten video/slides 2023? Also thanks for following up the line. @Andrew

@BastamTajik https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvIz-6YOdKs&t=1s
